# Load Error in require statement when using classes in multiple files

Tags: ruby, class, module

I'm pretty new to Ruby and facing a pretty basic problem i guess. I'm probably missing out on some basic concepts and constructs. So this is what i'm trying to do,

I'm writing a sinatra project, and i have a classes which are written in different files. The structure looks something of this sort,

```
project_name
- api.rb
- base.rb
- settings.rb
```

In my api.rb file i have defined a class and some methods, it also calls some methods form base.rb and base.rb calls some methods from settings.rb

In api.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'base'  --> This is the base.rb which is resulting in error

module XX
  class Api
    def some_method
      base = Base.new
      base.setup
      # some more code
    end
  end
end
```

In base.rb, it has the following code

```
require 'settings'

module XX
  class Base
    def setup
      # some code
    end

    def some_method
      #some code
    end
  end
end
```

When i just run ruby api.rb, i'm getting an error in the require statement, unable to load such file-- base (LoadError).

What is it that i'm missing here? Also, how is it that ruby know whether it a gem or a file required..does it check to see if the require  is a file in the project and then goes on to check for a gem ? How is this process done in ruby?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: to `require 'base'` you will need to add the directory to `LOAD_PATH` or use `require_relative`. `require` will search for the file requested in `LOAD_PATH` see [Docs Kernel#require](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) and [Kernel#require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

Comment: @engineersmnkyThanks! that did the trick. I should have read about the require statement before asking this question in SO. I feel so dumb :(